# Why do we show $<\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question

When we prove things like continuity in real analysis, why do we always aim for the result $<\epsilon$ when any positive multiple of $\epsilon$ proves the same result?

Comment: Getting $<10^{10} \epsilon$ is as good as getting $<\epsilon$.

Comment: For simplicity of exposition.

Comment: Remember, $\varepsilon > 0$ is simply an arbitrary positive number. Why dress it up with other multiples, when $\varepsilon$ can already be any positive value you want?

Comment: My question is more why do we bother undressing it with other multiplies, when they suffice for the proof

Comment: One could change the definition to "$<C\epsilon$ for any constant $C>0$ where $C$ is independent of $\epsilon$”. However this is much more complex. We now have three free numbers $\delta,\epsilon$ and $C$ in the definition. Its hard enough to get students to understand the usual definition. $C$ is also redundant as this formulation follows from the one you are used to. Thus we let the definition be as simple and clear as possible and leave consequences like the one you are referring to as a corollary of that definition.

Comment: @Loobear23 Oh, I think I see what you're asking. Why do we bother dealing with things like $\varepsilon / 2$, just so the end result is less than $\varepsilon$, when we could just end with $< 2\varepsilon$ and be done with it? Good question; not everyone does bother with this. I've seen plenty of arguments that end with $< 2\varepsilon$ or $< 4\varepsilon$, and nobody bats an eye. It is nice, though, when computing actual estimates, if the argument ends with $< \varepsilon$.

Comment: A reason is because you start by writing $<\epsilon$, and it can be psychologically heavy to change your mind.

You are right, this is not mandated.

Comment: Because that's the definition...

Answer (score 2):

We could use an alternative definition, consider the following alternative definition of convergence when it sufficies to prove for any positive multiple K of epsilon:

We say $x_n \rightarrow l$ when $(\exists K > 0)(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists N)(\forall n > N) |x_n - l| < K\epsilon$.

Then consider the proposition that if $x_n \rightarrow l, y_n \rightarrow l_2$ then $x_n + y_n \rightarrow l + l_2$.

Then we have for some $K$ and $K_2$, consider any $\epsilon > 0$
$$(\exists N)(\forall n > N) |x_n - l| < K\epsilon$$
$$(\exists N_2)(\forall n > N_2) |y_n - l_2| < K_2\epsilon $$

Then consider $M = N + N_2$:

$$(\exists M)(\forall n > M) |x_n + y_n - (l + l_2)| < (K+K_2)\epsilon $$

This means that the positive multiple is $K + K_2$ so the proposition holds.

The issue is that this is really ugly compared to just choosing half epsilon.

Comment: $(\exists K > 0)(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists N)(\forall n > N) |x_n - l| < \epsilon$. --> Is $K$ meant to be mentioned only once in this line?

Comment: Thank you, this was wrong and I've ammended it.

Comment: Also 2. did you mean like $K_1$ and $N_1$ later on or something? 3. I think one of the $N$'s should be $N_2$?

Comment: I didn't realise it could be that bad, thank you. I also needed to change to an M later.
In future I need to edit my answers better.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, that's not always what we do, because as you say, $<c\epsilon$ is enough, where $c\in(0,\infty)$.

However when you're taking a real analysis class (especially for the first time!) we want to make sure that what's obvious to the professor is also obvious (or at least understandable) to the student.  So we sometimes insist on $<\epsilon$ for that reason.

P.S. Some people do it for what they believe is simplicity or ease of reading.